# In fabric, how can I redirect the out of the 'local' command to the input of the 'run' command?

Tags: python, fabric

In fabric, how can I redirect the output of the `local` command to the input of `sudo` or `run` command.

I would like to use fabric to do something like:

```
cat install.sh | ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx sudo bash
```

Answer (score 0):

In fabric to do this a few different ways. You could just call this like you have above within a local() call. You could put("install.sh","/home/user") and then call it with run(). Or you could turn the install.sh commands into a fabfile using the api.